# Animation of a surface over time

Tags: plotting, export, animation

I have a function $f(x,y,t)$ that depends on the spatial variables "x" and "y" and the temporal variable "t". how can I do an animation in mathematica that shows the movement of the surface over time? in what formats this animation can be saved? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you give an example `f[x, y, t]` that you want to animate?

Comment: Yes, for example: f[x, y, t] = (Exp[x + t] - Exp[x - t]) Cos[y]

Comment: Perhaps it is also worth checking out the description for the [Animate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) function

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
f[x_, y_, t_] = (Exp[x + t] - Exp[x - t]) Cos[y]

Animate[Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}], {t, 0, 1}]



Animate[Plot3D[f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {-5.9, 9.9}], {t, 0, 1}]
```